# Limpar Context usando persistencia CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de "limpar" meu `context` utilizando o `Core Data`.

Pois tenho um problema em que quando atualizo o aplicativo, o mesmo após salvar os registros no banco de dados, também mantém no `context`. Sendo assim toda vez que vou mostrar na tela estes registros o mesmo mostra duplicado, pois ele pega do banco e o temporário que está no `context`.

Obs.: Já verifiquei e não tem registro duplicado no banco de dados.

Comment: Você precisa mostrar um pouco do código para termos ideia de como você puxa os dados e como você cria o context.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou "reset()" ou delete(item)?

No delete você tem que passar o item que quer limpar...